# how to use codey rocky as robot controlled by computer

Tags: linux, python

I have a old [Codey Rocky](https://www.makeblock.com/pages/codey-rocky-emo-robot), and I would like to use it as a regular robot, e.g. I can control it with my (linux) pc. I tried programming it with "python" using the mblock web interface, and adding `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/bin/python3`. however, when I do e.g. `ls /` to try and find out how to upload a real custom program, I cannot get the stdout. When using `os.system` in python, it raises an exception. not to mention that there is no way to even debug my python script, or see the output. Is there anyway to use the Codey Rocky as robot, being controlled by my system?

EDIT: i can now get stdout using my windows virtual machine; however, sadly adding #!/bin/sh at the start of the script does not work anymore because of the firmware update i just did

Comment: I use this kind of stuff in my basement workshop. You need to duplicate the setup it normally uses with your python code. I am not sure if this is even feasible.  I put the access software on a Windows instrumentation machine and that works fine.

Comment: @john what access software?

Comment: Parallax robotic software, Arduino IDE software, Digitrax firmware updating software and such like. Stamp (Parallax) and Arduino load code onto the device or robot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specifications:

```
Main control / chip ESP32 Processor 
Tensilica LX6 dual-core processor
Clock speed 240 MHz（Max）
Onboard sensor RGB LED module, button, potentiometer, sound sensor, light sensor, gyroscope, accelerometer, IR emitter, IR receiver, IR color sensor, LED matrix, speaker
Coding language Block-based, Python
Battery (included) 3.7V rechargeable LiPo battery
Battery capacity 950mAh
Playtime    ≈1- 2 hours
Charge time ≈ 1.5 hours
Rotational speed 250RPM
Communication mode USB, Bluetooth, Wi-Fi 
Compatibility LEGO bricks
```

would indicate this is a simple, closed kind of system that can only be run by its specified controls.

I would say (with reasonable certainty) that you cannot control this from an other computer with vanilla coding or access software on it.

These kind of devices (I have some here) need the specific software that comes with the device.

Such devices are too simplistic for generic software control.

Comment: but can i not use python to connect to my computer?

Comment: Yes.  I can build an Arduino robot car that looks like the Parallax  robot car but the software is not interchangeable and vanilla software will not control either. The devices are too simplistic for generic control